# Failed to create a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, nav2, global-planner, navfn

I am trying to run navigation with slam on a custom world. I am using the standard nav2fn planner. I first tried running it on my own urdf robot model. That didn't work so I tried using the turtle bot tutorial and I am getting the same error.

I am running :

```
ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py headless:=False slam:=True world:/path/my_world.world
```

After I give a goal in rviz the path is planned correctly and works for a bit and then as navigation continues I get this error

```
[ERROR] [1710457022.266415882] [planner_server]: FailedFailed to create a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen.
[WARN] [1710457022.266464837] [planner_server]: GridBased: failed to create plan with tolerance 2.50.
[WARN] [1710457022.266474122] [planner_server]: Planning algorithm GridBased failed to generate a valid path to (15.59, 0.71)
```

The path doesn't seem to be obstructed by anything by the time the error occurs (see below the state of the robot when I get the error and the program aborts).
The custom world is very large which may be an issue.

[image]

Based on this [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/350510/some-errors-when-using-globalplanner/) I tried changing the inflation/cost_scaling parameters.
I also tried using different BT like "navigate_w_recovery_and_replanning_only_if_path_becomes_invalid"" just for the heck of it.
None of it worked so far. I also have tried increasing the width/height of the local costmap (I increased it from 3 3 to 30 30, cuz any higher caused long freezes) .
-I can get the navigation working in the default turtle bot world (which again leads me to think the size of my world is the culprit). But I have no idea what the "Failed to create a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen." error means.

EDIT:
-I have tried using a different large custom world and I got the same issue, a path is found but eventually the error : "Failed to create a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen".